# How to get rid of old config connections in openvpn?

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I uninstalled openvpn software & deleted manually config (ovpn) file. Still showing old config connections in system tray.

I am using windows 7 OS.
I am asking about the following situation:

[image: this situation].

How to get rid of these 3 connections?